# Creating a Custom Social Connection for Reddit with Auth0

Tags: javascript, authentication, auth0

I’m trying to create a custom social connection for Reddit using Auth0. Here’s what I have set up so far:

- Authorization URL: https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize
- Token URL: https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
- Scope: identity,read,submit
- Client ID & secret taken from the Reddit app I created

I’ve also implemented the following Fetch User Profile Script:

```js
function(accessToken, ctx, cb) {
  request.get('https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me', {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
      'User-Agent': 'Auth0/1.0'
    }
  }, function(e, r, b) {
    if (e) return cb(e);
    if (r.statusCode !== 200) return cb(new Error('StatusCode: ' + r.statusCode));
    var profile = JSON.parse(b);
    cb(null, {
      user_id: profile.id,
      username: profile.name,
      email: profile.email || ''
    });
  });
}
```

However, when I try the connection, I get the following error:

```json
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "the connection is not enabled"
}
```

I’m not sure what I need to insert into the custom header. I found [this post](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-create-a-custom-social-connection-for-reddit-oauth-login/8281) but I’m still having trouble defining the user profile script and the custom header. Any help would be appreciated.